# How to make a dropdown list of all cultures (but no repeats)

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization, cultureinfo

I'm trying to make 2 dropdown lists.

The top one offers all cultures, (but no repeats).
Example: English, Spanish, Filipino

After selecting from the top list the bottom list will show any specific types.

I right now I use this code for my top list.

```
foreach (CultureInfo cultureInfo in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures))
```

However it does not show *Filipino (Philippines)*
I'd rather not use GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)) because it shows too many at once.

It seems like I may need to load NeutralCultures into an IList.
Then iterate through AllCultures to make sure it's ThreeLetterISOLanguageName is in the list, if not add it.

*There a best practice for this?*

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at the reference for the different [`CultureTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.culturetypes.aspx) values.  It tells you what is included for each.

I guess you want everything that's in all but the specific cultures?  You could either combine all non-specific cultures into a set or get all cultures and exclude the specific ones.  The second approach would be easiest to express in LINQ:

```
var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                          .Except(CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures));
```

Though it seems that since `CultureTypes` has the flags attribute, we could also just mask out the `SpecificCultures` when getting them.

```
var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(
    CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.SpecificCultures
);
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it works very well. I like how it has just English and French  - rather than the specifics. What I do not understand is why it will have Czech "cs-CZ" but not Filipino "fil-PH". Both are specific (only 1 country each).

Comment: @aron: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.  The first part of the name is just the [ISO 639-1 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) code while the second part is the [ISO 3166 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso_3166).  ISO 639-1 code alone refers to a language (a neutral culture not associated with a specific region).  Though the Czech Republic (`cs-CZ`) uses the the Czech language (`cs`), they are not equivalent.  Both of those are specific cultures and should not be listed here.  If it is, it is probably a culture object that was created by you (which is included).

Comment: Instead of calling `GetCultures` twice and using `Except`,  you can use `GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)`

Comment: @RuudLenders: You know, you're right. Inspecting the values and would suggest that should work, and the docs support that. Good call.

Comment: What does `(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)` mean? I am flabbergasted by the operators & and ~. I've researched a bit about these but I could not wrap my head around that line.

Comment: @KristianneNerona `CultureTypes` is a set of flags. It's just using bitwise operations to exclude a particular flag -- in this case, `SpecificCultures`.